# No longer able to access Centos 6 VPS the "normal" way?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, putty

So I still yes do have access to the serial console stuff but I am really limited on my options now.

I did numerous things before I had rebooted my VPS so I really can't pinpoint what I did to cause the issue.

I checked my ssh_config to ensure my port number/info was still the same and it in fact was. I ensured my VPS IP was not "magically" different.

Now when I select "open" on PuTTy I just get this nice error: http://puu.sh/5yzOf.png

I have access through serial console now and FTP no longer works..

All help is extremely appreciated. All I remember doing previous before rebooting was trying to get access to my sql dumps so I can re install the server since I had did some things incorrectly and caused heaps of issues.

If I am unable to get the SQL files I will have lossed an entire month worth of work :/

Comment: Make sure `sshd` is started. Make sure you aren't blocking the port with any firewalls (e.g. `iptables). Make sure you have anything like fail2ban disabled.

Comment: @Bob this is my output: http://puu.sh/5yAal.png when trying to start SSHD

Comment: SSHD now finally started, will report back in a few on my status.

Comment: @Bob thanks so much, with your question that lead me to go more in depth on that specific issue. Fixed it! If you'd had posted it as an answer I would be more than happy to mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error (connection refused) from PuTTY usually means the port is closed. This can mean that the server has reported that the port is closed, or a router somewhere along the way has. It does not mean that you can't reach the server - in that case, you get a timeout instead.

1. The first thing to check, usually, is to make sure your local router, if it's performing NAT, has forwarded the port correctly. As this is a VPS, presumably you don't have any NAT going on and your server is actually assigned that as a public IP.
2. The next thing is to make sure your SSH daemon is actually running. Check if `sshd` is running - the command `ps -e | grep 'sshd'` can be helpful here. Also check if it's running on the correct port and interface - `netstat -tulpn | grep 'sshd'` will work. The IP address should either be the one assigned to that interface, or `0.0.0.0` (`::` for IPv6) - this means 'all' IPs, in the context of a listening port. The bit after the last colon should be the correct port, default `22`.
3. Once you are sure the SSH server is running on the correct port, you may want to check and/or disable your firewall(s). The default one running is `iptables` - you can list the filter table with `iptables -L` - the `INPUT` chain should either be `policy ACCEPT` or have an `ACCEPT` entry for the SSH port. You might also be running other software like `fail2ban`, which 'bans' IPs after enough failed login attempts - read their documentation on how to unban yourself.